# Merging two Pandas series using a key

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am having two pandas series, namely, x and y.

x.head() gives:

```
   user  hotel  rating      id
0  1      1253       5  2783_1253
1  4       589       5   2783_589
2  5      1270       4  2783_1270
3  3      1274       4  2783_1274
4  2       741       5   2783_741
```

y.head() gives:

```
 UserID Gender   Age  Occupation Zip Code
0     1.0      F  18.0      10.0    48067
1     2.0      M  56.0      16.0    70072
2     3.0      M  25.0      15.0    55117
3     4.0      M  45.0       7.0     2460
4     5.0      M  25.0      20.0    55455
```

What I need is to merge columns of these two where user = UserID.

So for example my first row should look like:

```
   user  hotel  rating      id         UserID Gender   Age  Occupation Zip Code
0  1    1253      5      2783_1253     1.0      F     18.0     10.0     48067
```

How will I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first convert `float` column to `int` and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
y['user'] = y.UserID.astype(int)
df = pd.merge(x,y, on='user')
print (df)
   user  hotel  rating         id  UserID  Gender Age  Occupation   Zip   Code
0     1   1253       5  2783_1253     1.0     2.0   M        56.0  16.0  70072
1     4    589       5   2783_589     4.0     5.0   M        25.0  20.0  55455
2     3   1274       4  2783_1274     3.0     4.0   M        45.0   7.0   2460
3     2    741       5   2783_741     2.0     3.0   M        25.0  15.0  55117
```

Or convert both columns to `float`:

```
x['UserID'] = x.user.astype(float)
df = pd.merge(x,y, on='UserID')
print (df)
   user  hotel  rating         id  UserID  Gender Age  Occupation   Zip   Code
0     1   1253       5  2783_1253     1.0     2.0   M        56.0  16.0  70072
1     4    589       5   2783_589     4.0     5.0   M        25.0  20.0  55455
2     3   1274       4  2783_1274     3.0     4.0   M        45.0   7.0   2460
3     2    741       5   2783_741     2.0     3.0   M        25.0  15.0  55117
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks it helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a join. You will find your answer here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html (it works just like in SQL).
However, there might some additional casting and renaming if you want to keep both `user` as an integer and `UserID` as a float.